# Need to change a dicts values in an object everytime its called

Tags: python, pygame

Im making an RPG with python and pygame. I have an item class that returns a dict with various item attributes based on a random item number. The problem im having is when i make multiple calls to the item, the same item spawns and I wanted different items to spawn.

Code:

```
class Item(SpriteBase):
 def __init__(self, game, type, x, y):
    self.groups = game.allSprites, game.itemSprites
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    self.game = game
    self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
    self.image.fill(LIGHT_GREY)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.x = x * TILESIZE
    self.y = y * TILESIZE
    self.item = {'item No.': '',
                 'name': '',
                 'rarity': '',
                 'durability': 0,
                 'damage': 0,
                 'type': '',
                 'splashText': '',
                 'image': ''
                 }

 def set_attributes(self):
    randomItemNumber = randint(0, 9)
    with open(path.join(itemFolder, 'itemList'), 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            no_new_lines = line.rstrip('\n')
            split_lines = no_new_lines.split('|')
            if int(split_lines[0]) == randomItemNumber:
                self.item['item No.'] = split_lines[0]
                self.item['name'] = split_lines[1]
                self.item['durability'] = int(split_lines[3])
                self.item['damage'] = int(split_lines[4])
                self.item['type'] = split_lines[5]
                self.item['splashText'] = split_lines[6]
                print(self.item)

 def add_to_inventory(self):
    if pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.game.player, self.game.itemSprites, True):
        self.game.player.inventory.append(self.item)
        print('player inventory: {}.'.format(self.game.player.inventory))

 def update(self):
    self.add_to_inventory()
    self.rect.x, self.rect.y = self.x, self.y
```

And when its called:

```
    for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map.data):
        for col, tiles in enumerate(tiles):
             if tiles == '\'':
                Item(game=self, type='Weapon', x=col, y=row)
                for item in self.itemSprites:
                    item.set_attributes()
```

Comment: Unable to understand the problem. Are you saying when you call `set_attributes()` the item values are not changing?

Comment: When more than one item is created the values aren't changing. I wanted the values to change everytime an item instance is created.

Comment: Ok, where are you creating more than one item? Can you please add this in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment yet, so I write an answer.

Couple of comments here:

First, in your second code block, second for loop, don't call your variable tiles again, it will mess with the first for loop. And I don't understand why you set_attributes every time you create a new item. It should be more like this below:

> ```
> for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map.data):
>     for col, current in enumerate(tiles):
>          if current == '\'':
>              Item(game=self, type='Weapon', x=col, y=row)
> for item in self.itemSprites:
>     item.set_attributes()
> ```

Second, could you post some lines of 'itemList', and also your 'SpriteBase' class?

Obviously each item should be different since you are calling randint every time you set the attributes, so it is very likely a case where you are instantiating the same object when you are going through the game.itemSprite list.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the item list is set up like this:

`Item#|ItemName|Rarity|Durability|Damage|Type|SplashText`

also now that I look at it, I don't really use much of the sprite base class. It should really just be (pg.sprite.Sprite)

Comment: Yes, use the Sprite class, since this is the constructor that you're using afterward. Try to add the group after calling the constructor, it would look like: `pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self); self.add(self.groups)`